# How to pin images for offline use with Glide?

Tags: android, image-loading, android-glide

I have a list of photos that I want to display so I am using a `RecyclerView` and a `RecyclerView.Adapter`. So when I bind the view in `onBindViewHolder()`, I do something like this:

```
// photo is a Object that contains a url
// photoViewHolder.photo is the imageview
Glide.with(photoViewHolder.photo.getContext()) //use the imageview context
                .load(photo.getPhotoScaledURL())//load the photo using an url
                .into(photoViewHolder.photo); //into the imageview
```

But here I am always relying on the URL. Would I be able to somehow always have this image cached? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To show some of the images offline first download your image and store the path in DB.Now whenever you offline show the downloaded image.And when online just check the whether image is already downloaded or not, If downloaded then show downloaded image else use glide.